# Unable to run app created in xcode on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, codesign, ios10, xcode8

I want to learn IOS development and so I installed xcode and tried running my first app on my iPhone.

I'm using xcode 8 beta 6 and my iPhone is running the latest beta of IOS 10.

I have an Apple ID as a developer account, but I'm not part of the Apple Developer program, for which you have to pay.

I have selected my iPhone under "Device" and when I click the play button I get "build failed" and the following error messages:

> Signing for "My First Project" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>
> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727099/how-to-run-apps-on-iphone-ipad-using-xcode-7-without-enrolling-to-apples-develo)
, but since it's about other versions, the solution doesn't apply to me.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: How do I get from this screen to the one Where you have to pick the team?]

Comment: please select development team. in general -> team

Comment: first you generate profile and certificate?

Comment: Do you mean in Preferences - General? Because there doesn't seem to be a "team" option there

Comment: Do you have the necessary provisioning profile?

Comment: I have an Apple ID as a developer account, but I'm not part of the Apple Developer program, for which you have to pay.

Comment: add your Apple ID to xcode -  prefernce - account and then select that id from general -> team

Comment: I added the account, how do I get in general - team? There is no general option anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your Apple ID to xcode - prefernce - account and then select that id from general -> team

please see the screen where you have to select team which is your Apple ID

[image]

Comment: you have to select target not project option in my screen blue one is

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. This indeed worked.

Comment: it's ok bro best of luck for new development

Comment: Strangely, I am also running Xcode 8, beta 6, and the Signing interface looks nothing like this. Instead, I am seeing this: http://tinypic.com/r/bfqmpy/9

Comment: hi you get solution ?