# Unable to run Xcode swift program on actual devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a developer new to Xcode swift projects.

I have created a program that gives me no error when I run it on a simulated iPhone. However, once I connect my own device to my laptop to run my program, this is what it shows me. Apparently, there are two errors specific to actual devices that I am unable to locate.

[image: screenshot]

Can some help me fix this please? Thank you so much!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: "This is what it shows me"? What?!? You did not provide either code or the error that you're getting, so how can we possibly help you?

Comment: Turns out the image link was hidden. Fixed it.

Comment: @Erica wang check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic/39930139#39930139

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039271/unable-to-run-app-created-in-xcode-on-iphone