# How to run iOS app on Macbook Simulator without any Apple Store Account?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible, I want to run my first app on Macbook Simulator, but I have no Apple account. I have already created Apple Store account, but they are asking for a payment of 99$. So I just want to check my app will be run or not on Apple simulator, if it will be run then I will pay on Apple Store.

Can I use that app on my simulator without any apple paid service. And I have not got any iPhone also, I just bought Macbook Air.

Comment: TO run the app on the simulator you don't need to pay or have the developer account, you can directly run on simulator

Comment: Hi Iraniya,
when i am run my ios app on simulator, then display error, you need to create team. when i have add team, then also display error, that team is "it requires a provisioning profile in xcode" .

Comment: Hi iraniya, can you tell me step by step, how can i run ios app on simulator ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727099/how-to-run-apps-on-iphone-ipad-using-xcode-7-without-enrolling-to-apples-develo check this question

Comment: After create new team, they are display 2 error 1) "cannot create a ios development provising profile 'com.appname' your development team doesnt support the push notification and in app purchase capability " 2) No profile for 'com.appname' were found"

Comment: Hi Iraniya, can you tell me how to use "push notifcation" and 
in app purchase" , in existing project. because i just use web view app .  so please help me for that. then i will run that app on my simulator.

Comment: @Ishangarg for implementing PushNotification and InAppPurchase u need a developer account and device. On Simulator these feature's can't be implemented.

Comment: Hi shivam i have buy @99 membership on apple store. So can anyone suggest me, i am using wordpress site, and i am uploading on apple store as webview app. but apple has reject my app due to webview functions as 4.2.0 section. so please suggest me some native function for my app then i will use native function in app and apple will approve that. i have use header, side navigation, footer tabs. push notification, loading indicator. but those are not enough to show native functions. please suggest better native function, what will i use?

Comment: Hello , apple store are not accepting my ios app . and i have bought $99 plan for ios app from apple store. so can anyone suggest me, what can i do for that, users can download .ipa file from my own website.