# Developing an iOS app without an internet connection?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, internet-connection

I am developing an iOS app and I have just found myself in a situation where my internet connection cut out and now that it is back it is spotty. When deploying XCode complains "process launch failed: security", which means I am not able to continue developing and testing. The application is already signed in XCode for my user and I have been able to deploy the same app while there has been a good internet connection.

Is there any way to develop and deploy the app to my phone without an active internet connection? I am hoping there is, otherwise it is going to cramp my "develop while roaming" style.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824908/xcode-process-launch-failed-security

Comment: Seems to work sometimes and then it forgets. Either way, I'll defer to post you referenced.

Comment: @Andre M, do you finaly get the way to make Xcode working without active internet connection?

Comment: @Jeff.Lu I did not. It looks like XCode needs to talk home, to Apple, for signing purposes.