# Ad-Hoc distribution for iOS app

Tags: ios, authorization, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to release an invite-only iOS App. I don't particularly want this app on the App Store, and using TestFlight causes a lot of problems (having to constantly update binaries, limited users... Apple IDs).

At the same time I'd rather not have to resort to a third party distribution [to get this kind of an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application).

Is it possible to release a **secret** invite-only App on the App Store?

Comment: You can add up to 1000 external testers by iTunesConnect. It does not need device's uuid. And these external testers use TestFlight app to get your app. Another option for you is http://hockeyapp.net

Comment: Builds in iTunes Connect expire after 30 days. HockeyApp is a paid alternative, I should probably look into that and the Apple Developer Enterprise Program.

Comment: Does HockeyApp give off any 'third party' alerts?

Answer (score 2):

Consider enrolling for an [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) 
This will cost more but then you can distribute using your server . You can use MDM also no need to upload or use test flight.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the last time you used Test Flight, but it has changed a lot in the last year.  There can still be headaches with it, but since it was bought by Apple you now distribute your App through [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) which is the same way you would do it for releasing in the App store.  You have a number of beta testers (up to 1000) that all you need is their email address.  You can also have internal testers (up to 25 I think) which will get every build you upload automatically (however they do have some access to the information about your app through their iTunes accounts).

So in summary it takes the same amount of work and the same process to have beta testers that it does to release it through the App Store **except** that you don't have to wait the 5+ days for the App review.  Do note that the beta version will expire after 30 days at which point you just need to upload a new one.

Comment: For Pre-released apps in iTunes Connect you must update your build every 30 days or else the app expires

Answer (score 1):

You cannot release a **secret** App on the App Store, as it violated [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> 2.22 Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected