# How to create ipa without Apple Developer Program in Xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode7, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

What i am trying to do is `create an ipa` using Xcode7 for ad hoc distribution. I haven't done it earlier, this is my first try. Searched s/o and get to know that earlier it is possible to create ipa file with Xcode5. I was trying the [way explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account) But I am not getting the option to select export which is shown in the screenshot. I think apple may have changed it, now we can select the export file after signIn with the apple id registered in apple developer membership. I am attaching the screenshot that comes after `Product > Archive`. As you can see that the export option is disabled, and it is asking for apple developer membership, but able to see the archive file in the finder. Is there any way to create ipa without apple developer membership.[image]

Comment: Please down-vote with the reason

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it by this way:

1)Clean your project.

2)Build your project.

3)Go to products menu -> select build for -> select Profiling.

4)In project navigator, find you .app product.

5)Right click on it and click show in finder.

6)There you will find folder naming "Release-iphoneos", in this folder you will find your .app extension file.

7)Create a folder named "Payload", copy that .app file in this folder.

8)Archive your folder.

9)After archive, rename your folder to name of your app and change its extension from ".zip" to ".ipa"

10)Your IPA is ready for sharing.

You can install This IPA directly from iTunes below 12.7.

If you are using iTunes 12.7 and above you can use [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) to share your IPA for installation. [Here is a good step by step process available.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26904969/3824808)

Comment: Thanks Akshay...But after installing the ipa on device, I get the warning "Untrusted Developer". Is it normal or, i did something wrong.

Comment: There is some change in the step, I didn't find the folder "Release-iphoneos". So i skipped the step 6, Directly added a folder named it "Payload", zipped it and step 9, 10.

Comment: I know why "Untrusted developer" warning comes and how to to resolve it. Just want to confirm.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application

Comment: You didn't found "Release-iphoneos" it may be because your build configuration in profile scheme is set to debug.

Comment: Got it, can I distribute this ipa remotely for testing. i thin I can't cause the code-SignIn issue will come on the other device, right?

Comment: Yes, you can distribute ipa for testing. But make sure that your adhoc profile contains device's udid otherwise it won't install.

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani I have duly followed your instructions. However, when I try to install the ipa from iTunes on my iOS device, it says installing and then the app disappears. What could be the issue?

Comment: @HellsGuardian issue can be with the provisioning profile you are using to make ipa.

Comment: I am very new to this so I am unable to find the issue. Could you help me?

Comment: @HellsGuardian For building an IPA or a build for you iPhone device, you need provisioning profile and development certificate. If you are a free account user then Xcode handle it for you add the device automatically to your account once you connect the device with Xcode. You need to check if your device is included in the provisioning profile if it is not included then it won't work. You can include a device to your account from apple developer center under managing device section.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So in order for me to install the ipa on other devices, they must be included in the provisioning profile. However, when I log in to the apple developer center, there is no manage device section in my account. There's Downloads, Documentation, Forums, Bugs, News on the side and there is Downloads Tools, Build your first App, Join the Apple Developer Program in the center. Nothing else.

Comment: Go in Xcode, in project settings section go in the general section. Check what team and provisioning profile are showing there. You will get an idea from there what account you are using. It might not be showing in developer account as you are free account user. You need to get enrolled into apple developer.

Comment: Are you saying it can't be done without enrolling into the apple developer program?

Comment: It can be but you need to connect your device to your xcode, then xcode itself add that device to yours account and then you can install from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142835/discussion-between-hells-guardian-and-akshay-sunderwani).

Comment: I can't install the ipa, it gets stuck on installing and nothing happens, also if this a an issue with device UDID's this won't work. Also as you said I dont think XCode automatically add the device once it's connected.

Comment: @TejasK, The issue can be anything, it can be that your certificate expired or you might not have device udid in your provisioning profile. If you are a free user then it might also be a reason as there is no manual way to create provisioning profile from developer center by adding udid, Xcode automatically manages it.

Comment: I used this for my application in Xcode 9 But It doesn't worked I know that with iTunes 12.7 we can't copy ipa files so I used apple configurator 2 to copy and install ipa file But I got the error with this description Information about an app could not be read. [ConfigurationUtilityKit.error – 0x194 (404)]

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani after installing to my iphone i got error "unable download this app", can you help ?

Comment: @Chielarck sure can you cross check the provisioning profile you are using for build and the device id if that is present in the same provisioning profile?

Comment: After step 5, kindly make sure that the build is in the Release or Debug folder according to your need. I accidentally sent a Debug build once because it navigated me to that folder, although I had built it in Release mode. So be careful.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to have a developer account.

You could also do the following:

Select "Save For Ad Hoc Deployment" & Click Next. Then open the "select a development team" drop down. It will have the option "Use Local singing assets" at the bottom. Select this option & Click Choose.

Here you go. The build will be created by Xcode without Apple ID Account.

Comment: From where I would get the option "Save For Ad Hoc Deployment". I am not getting this option, please check the screenshot.

Comment: Check this link   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html


Also make sure you have the AdHoc Provisional Profile in your local machine