# IOS Developer create an ipa without payment

Tags: ios, ipa

I want to create ipa of my application. Do I have to pay money to get developer certificate for generate ipa for application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ipa without Apple Developer Progromammer in Xcode7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403969/how-to-create-ipa-without-apple-developer-progromammer-in-xcode7)

Comment: You need a provisioning profile and developer p12 files to generate an ipa file. Without provisioning profile no point of generating ipa file, because you can not install on any devices.

Comment: Not possible, Apple wants you to pay for Developer programa in order to let you install apps on devices. But you can run them for free on the simulator.