# Get ipa from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ipa

I want to export ipa file for my project and sign it manually with my friends enterprise account Is there a way to export unsigned ipa without paid developer account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ipa without Apple Developer Program in Xcode7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403969/how-to-create-ipa-without-apple-developer-program-in-xcode7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
step1: search ".app" in project navigator (xcode left side
step2: right click on projectname.app and select "show in finder"
step3: copy projectname.app into a empty folder and zip the folder(foldername.zip)
step4: change the zipfolder extension to .ipa(foldername.zip -> foldername.ipa)
step5: now you have the final .ipa file , you can use it for further needs
```