# Could not launch app (Verify the Developer App certificate)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an issue sometime when I run the app in my iPhone with Xcode.
[image: Message in Xcode]

I tried to verify apps in Settings but it didn't work. "Unable to Verify "iPhone Developer: ..." Apps.

I am a Free developer but it normally runs and sometime during 1 hour I can't run anything on my iPhone.

I tried to delete the app and run, to download all profiles in Xcode Settings, same problem.

Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to run the app from the iPhone, and not from xcode, and see if it's working

Comment: You can refer this [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application). You may find solution.

Comment: @Roee84 : I have the message telling me to trust the developer in settings.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara : Already tried those solutions but none of them seems to work with me. Trust Developer never work

Comment: Problem solved: My Wifi block the verification (Don't know why) and it worked with 3G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wifi connection had proxy which blocked the verification in iPhone settings. 
Switch to 3G/4G was the solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had to actually tap the app icon on the iPhone device to launch the app and only then did the iPhone prompt me to Trust the certificate.

I had nothing appropriate listed in Settings > General > Profiles (Settings > General > Device Management on later versions of iOS).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Error message]

There are two solution for this:

**A. Solution 1:**

1. Run app on device. You should be able to alert *’Trust This Computer’*?
2. Tap on *Trust* option
3. Enter device passcode
4. Open *Settings* app. Goto *Device Management*.

[image: Screenshot-2]

5. Here you’ll be able to see list of profiles used for installing apps on device. *Select profile* is used to run app on device.
6. Tap on *Trust “Apple Development:…”*
7. Again you’ll be able to see confirmation pop up alert. Tap on *Trust*.
8. Now you’ll see that *App is verified* for device.

[image: Screenshot-3]

**B. Solution 2:**

If your **device is not connected to internet/wifi** then Xcode shows “*Verify the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device…*”. Connect your device to internet/wifi and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used provisioning profile is distribute not development, in my case, it is.

When I saw this in Xcode, but there is nothing needs to verify in Settings > General > Profiles, then I just click app on my phone to run it, and system showing a alert view to let me trust it, after TRUST IT, app run well. And after this, you can run app using Xcode, but Xcode will show "process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

resetting network settings fixed my issue: https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/cellular-data-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, tried restarting the device and XCode multiple times, nothing seemed to help.

It was my-bad actually, I had added a new external dependency using `Carthage` and had forgotten to include it in the `Build Phases --> Run Script --> /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks` section.

Answer (score -2):

"A network connection is required to verify."  You have to have a valid internet connection (whether 3G/4G data or wifi) or else it won't verify. When it doesn't work for me it's always due to my router being jacked up.

Comment: This is a good answer. If your device is not connected to internet - Xcode shows "verify the developer app certificate..." message even if you already made necessary changes in device's settings.