# Automatically trust enterprise app developer

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, code-signing, enterprise

I understand that Enterprise apps need to be "trusted" before users can use them. ["Untrusted App Developer" message when installing enterprise iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application) this answers details what I mean.

However, it's quite a horrible experience having users to go to Settings > General > Device Management blah blah to trust an Enterprise profile. Is there a programmatic way (URL scheme maybe?) to automatically launch to the said menu so all the user has to do is tap "trust"?

Thanks!

Comment: most close URL I found is `App-Prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList`

Comment: and can you launch this from Safari like so: `App-Prefs://root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList` ? I opened it in Safari and a popup appeared: "Want to open this in Settings?". Then I tapped "open" and another pop up appeared: "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid." and the page just sits there. I've read somewhere that this might not work anymore in iOS 10..

Comment: No, I didn't try that from Safari.

Comment: if we can't launch this from Safari, I don't see a way to launch this..