# iOS enterprise app trust expires when offline

Tags: ios, ipad, certificate, mdm, mobileiron

We have an internal enterprise app distributed by our MDM system (MobileIron).

The app runs as expected at first but after a while (around 30 days) we start getting reports from the facilities using the app the it does not start anymore.
All facilities are **offline** so the iPads running the app are only connected to internet when installing/upgrading the app.

> It seems like the Enterprise Developer trust is expired or has been
>   revoked

[image: It seems like the Enterprise Developer trust is expired/revoked]

My question: Does anyone know how the trust system works? We thought that it should be possible to distribute enterprise apps and keep them on the iPad for about a year (as long as the provisioning certificate is valid).

I can also mention that earlier we used Apple Profile Manager to distribute the apps and we did not encounter this problem back then. We have also updated to iOS 10 on the iPads, they were running mainly on iOS 7 and 8 earlier.

Comment: Have you trusted the developer with these [5 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30762351/4739420)?

Comment: @ChristopherStephan yes we have. The app works fine to begin with, so it is initially trusted.