# Why I cannot Verify custom enterprise apps on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, deployment, enterprise, ios9.3

We distribute the test versions of our iOS apps through HockeyApp custom enterprise app store. Because of ASPN shenanigans our iOS developer refreshed some of our certificates. Since our two recent releases I cannot start the apps because they are from an "untrusted developer".

The procedure for this would be easy normally, you just have to navigate to `Settings -> General -> Device Management > Enterprise App > ...` and manually `Trust` them (I've been there before and I've done that in the past ["Untrusted App Developer" message when installing enterprise iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application), https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460). But I get a nonsensical error suggesting that I'm not connected to the internet. Since I'm connected to wifi the verification obviously fails because of another reason, but I don't know why.

My iPad is a 3rd gen iPad with the latest possible iOS: 9.3.5.

[image]

Now I got to the point that I deleted all the apps belonging our enterprise developer organization. After that I first trusted the organization itself, which was successful. I installed again only the two problematic newest app releases so I can verify them. But I still get this nonsensical error. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Someone else from our company could successfully install our HockeyApp apps onto another iOS 9.3.5 iPad. That ruled out iOS 9 as a cause of this.
2. Then I removed my iPad from the registered devices in HockeyApp's management interface.
3. When I tried to add it back I had to install HockeyApp's profile (that contains a few certificates related to HockeyApp, and it's needed to be install first so that I could install actual HockeyApp distributed applications.
4. I received an error while trying to install HockeyApp's profile saying that my iPad is not activated 0_O

[image]

4. I struggled with that for a good while until I manually restarted the iPad and low and behold it started to go through the activation procedure.
5. After activation, bootup and login I also signed out with my iCloud account from the AppStore settings and signed back in (just to be safe).
6. Then I could install the HockeyApp profile and now when I install the actual apps we distribute through HockeyApp I don't have to Trust them manually any more.

Comment: Met the same issue. In my case, a hard reboot was needed.

Comment: Note that HoxkeyApp is purchased by Microsoft and is now AppCenter. For AppCenter one needs to install the enterprise certificate as well.

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure that your apps where revoked, try putting them under a different developer, if you did not make the enterprise app please contact the developer of the app